# Export an Array of Arrays to Excel in php

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I have an Array of arrays at the beginning of each sub array is the header of the column followed by integers that I want to populate the column. It looks something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => How was the Food? [1] => 3 [2] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => How was the first party of the semester? [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 0 ) )
```

Is there a way to break up the array and get it to export to Excel?

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't want to export to a non-proprietary format like CSV?

Comment: I could do either. Excel would just be the preferred choice

Comment: you want it from the web or you want the code to generate the excel in the server?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Excel can open csv  file directly ... try

```
$array = Array (
        0 => Array (
                0 => "How was the Food?",
                1 => 3,
                2 => 4 
        ),
        1 => Array (
                0 => "How was the first party of the semester?",
                1 => 2,
                2 => 4,
                3 => 0 
        ) 
);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"demo.xls\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
foreach ($array as $data)
{
    fputcsv($out, $data,"\t");
}
fclose($out);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm thank you so much!!! You just saved me another night of no sleep

Comment: how to bold a value in excel?

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to export array to excel, have a look at [PHPReport](http://vernes.github.com/PHPReport/). I have written that class to simplify exporting with phpexcel. It supports xls and xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of exporting array to excel is here.

```
    $data = array(
         '0' => array('Name'=> 'Parvez', 'Status' =>'complete', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'001'),
         '1' => array('Name'=> 'Alam', 'Status' =>'inprogress', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'111'),
         '2' => array('Name'=> 'Sunnay', 'Status' =>'hold', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'333'),
         '3' => array('Name'=> 'Amir', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'444'),
         '4' => array('Name'=> 'Amir1', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777'),
         '5' => array('Name'=> 'Amir2', 'Status' =>'pending', 'Priority'=>'Low', 'Salary'=>'777')
        );
        $filename =  time().".xls";      
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

        ExportFile($data);
        function ExportFile($records) {
            $heading = false;
                if(!empty($records))
                  foreach($records as $row) {
                    if(!$heading) {
                      // display field/column names as a first row
                      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
                      $heading = true;
                    }
                    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
                }
            exit;
        }
```