# How to export php array to excel file(.xlsx)?

Tags: php, excel

I am currently working on exporting a php array to a .xlsx file. And this is how the array looks like:

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(24) "Company" [2]=> string(9) " 12345689" [3]=> string(9) "Name" [4]=> string(1) "4" [5]=> string(26) "careerintern2017@gmail.com"}
```

I'd like to export this array to format like:

```
id | ent_name | ent_num  | owner | ent_c | email 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Company  | 123456789| Name  | 4     | careerintern2017@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
$excel_file_path = "ent_info/ent_info_list.xlsx";
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($excel_file_path);
$row_num = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
$row_num =$row_num+1;
$col_num=0;
$counter=1;
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
foreach($array as $data){
    $pos = get_excel_col($col_num).$row_num;
        //$pos = A2, B2, C2 .... (for example)
    $sheet->setCellValue($pos, $data);
    if($counter==6){
        $row_num++;
        $col_num=0;
    }
    $col_num++;
    $counter++;
}
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
$writer->save($excel_file_path);
```

Yet, after executing this, it showed nothing on the excel .xlsx file. Is there anything missing above for writing data to an excel file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424847/export-an-array-of-arrays-to-excel-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the below? according to the [doc](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/#setting-a-cell-value-by-coordinate), it retrieves the cell (`$pos`) and sets the value.

Make sure `$pos` has value as well

```
var_dump($pos);//just to see which cell it is
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell($pos)
    ->setValue('Some value');
```